# Click outside to close the image lightbox on mobile

Tags: jquery, fancybox

"Click outside the image" does close the image lightbox on desktop but not on mobile.. How to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

There is an option `mobile` that is used to override options when mobile device is detected, therefore you can set `mobile: { clickSlide : 'close' }`;

Comment: Thank you. Where to add it? Tried it at the very end and it didn't work.